# Refresh HTML Page in Browser Automatically after 5 seconds and scroll to bottom

Tags: html, refresh, page-refresh

I'm not familiar with HTML but I need to do a simple modification to an existing code. I've got an HTML document which can be modified in Word (you can enter text passages).

If you access the document with an Webbrowser, it does automatically refresh every 5 seconds in order to show the latest modifications other users did in Word. The only problem is that it does not scroll down to the latest text passage someone entered.

Currently, I'm using this code for refreshing the page:

```
<meta http-equiv=refresh content=5>
```

Is there anything I could simply add in order to make the page scroll down to the bottom every time it refreshes automatically?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

For HTML Part...

```
<body onload="goDown()">
```

For the javascript part...
Add jquery.js on the HTML file..otherwise the javascript code won't work..

```
function goDown(id) {
   var div = document.getElementById(id);
   $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight
   }, 800);
}
```

This will automatically scroll to the bottom of the page on refresh.
You can add any time delay instead of 800... as per your requirements..

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I add the function right beneath this piece of code: <meta http-equiv=refresh content=5>

Comment: It's recommended to put JavaScript always at the bottom of the document.. but you can add it within scripts tag below the meta tag line.